# Setting up a MIPS test environment

Tags: c++, c, linux, unit-testing, mips

We are creating a multi platform software in C++ for "normal" i386 Linux, but also some obscure MIPS hardware and for this we cross compile our product using the ELDK Mips cross compiler (an older version). The software is copied automatically to the real hardware via a script placed on a USB stick (the hardware detects the insertion of the USB stick, searches for the script, copies, reboots).

The compilation of the product happens on the same machine (Linux i386) for both the MIPS and i386. We have a complete set of unit tests, and they are executed automatically upon the completion of the i386 build (results are interpreted via atlassian bamboo's junit parser, but this is not relevant here)... However we have a problem verifying the validity MIPS tests. There are some minor differences in the code when compiling in MIPS so it would be important to know that they work too.

And the question: How to set up a MIPS unit test environment that can take the compiled unit tests and run them? (Any solution is welcome, even the un-orthodox ones)

Comment: You could try to add MIPS support to [scratchbox2](https://maemo.gitorious.org/scratchbox2/pages/Home), looks like it only supports ARM for now.

Comment: QEMU supports MIPS, IIRC. It's not very fast though.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: @stviper yup, still looking!

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of virtual machine where you can execute your mips binaries?

Comment: @stviper Yes, something like that.

Comment: Have you check some of this http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Emulators

Comment: Check also this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859540/how-to-debug-mips-elf there is mentioned another emulator http://www.aurel32.net/info/debian_mips_qemu.php